# Problems embedding mp4 video

Tags: html, video, html5-video, mp4

I'm trying to use the html5 video tag to embed an mp4 but I'm having some issues that vary across different browsers.

My code looks like this:

```
<video controls="controls" width="640" height="360">
    <source src="http://www.mydomain.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

IE - Won't recognize the file when trying to embed (edit: IE was actually dragging on the file size not the format) and when the uri to my video is plugged into the address bar it opens the video in windows media player.

Chrome, Firefox - Simply will not recognized the file format (edit: Firefox was dragging on the size as well, Chrome was the only browser having issues) and when the uri is plugged into the address bar it attempts to play the video within the browser but fails.

Could there be something within the file that would prevent it from being embedded? If so, how can I find this out?

Comment: Make sure the server is sending the right header with the file. Should be "Content-Type: video/mp4". Also, as below, Firefox won't play mp4, so you need webm as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that the browsers are not supporting MP4, because it is a proprietary format.  To get the best cross-browser support you'll have to also encode your video in WebM and Ogg/Vorbis formats and then add those files to your `video` tag with their own `source` tags.

Just because a browser will play a video if you navigate directly to the video's URL does not mean that the browser supports that format. Usually, navigating straight to the video causes the browser to play the video with a plug-in such as Quicktime or VLC that has much better codec support than the browser does.

Comment: Is there a decent online tool that will convert mp4 to ogg and webm?

Comment: @brandozz I'm using [Firefogg](http://firefogg.org/) which has the ability to convert HD mp4 (1080p) to HD ogg/theora files. It also supports WebM.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm providing all formats now and it seems to be working across all browsers. Was it not working in chrome because of the H.264 codec? Once added the ogg version as a source, chrome played it without issue.

Comment: *"Just because a browser will play a video if you navigate directly to the video's URL ..."* Hmm... so in an attempt to work around this I also tried using an `iframe` with `src` set to the video, using a video that plays OK if I navigate directly to it, and still had the same issue. I expected the iframe to use the same playback method as directly navigating to the content used, but I guess it isn't? Is that expected behavior?

Comment: Although, fwiw, I just noticed that when you load a video directly in Chrome all it does is create a web page with a `video` element and display it through that. So it should use the same playback mechanism regardless of how you view the content. Ah well.

Answer (score 0):

try this  without that "/"

```
<video controls="controls" width="640" height="360">
<source src="http://www.mydomain.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
<source src="http://www.mydomain.com/video.ogg" type="video/ogg" >
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks @dhanasekar, this now appears to be isolated to my chrome browser. I've tested the video in other individuals chrome browsers and it plays fine. Not sure what the difference is at this point.