# My embedded mp4 is not working on html

Tags: html, mp4

I'm trying to embed an mp4 file into my html. Here's my code snippet:

```
<div class="bsu logo">
   <embed src="video/gian.mp4" style="width:960px;height:500px;">
</div>
```

The play bar is playing but only showing blank video. When I'm trying to embed other .mp4 video it's playing.

Comment: "When I'm trying to embed other .mp4 video it's playing" — Which implies that the problem is with the file, not with the code.

Comment: Hi @Quentin. I can play the mp4 file alone but when I'm embedding it, it doesn't play anymore.

Comment: Well you don't have a `type` attribute...have you tried adding one?

Comment: your question may have already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588654/why-wont-some-mp4-files-play-via-html5

Comment: @TylerH I tried added **type="video/mp4"** but the same problem exist

Comment: May be the codec of the file is different, you can try if it work in other browsers or try converting to other web supported format. Also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455797/problems-embedding-mp4-video