# why html mp4 video doesn't work in tomcat?

Tags: html, tomcat

I put below code in tomcat html pages, but it doesn't work. In client browser it always show streaming progress but can't see video content.

```
<video width='640' controls><source src='img/1.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>
```

I'm sure img/1.mp4 is here, the path is correct. If replace above line with img tag and an image file, it works great.

If copy that html from tomcat to local and open it from browser, it also works. So I think there should be something related to tomcat settings.

Comment: Guaranteed it's something to do with `mp4` encoding on their browser, or `mp4` unsupported encoding over HTTPS. I've had to deal with this a lot... frankly, if it's possible, it's better to have an `unlisted Youtube video` and just embed it that way :S

Comment: Read here for more info: [MP4 Encoding issues in browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24456179/11700321)